# Using pyHook to detect key up and down

Tags: python, keylogger, pyhook

I found script that by using pyHook could print mouse clicking up and down:

```
class record(object):
    def OnMouseEvent(self, event):
        print 'MessageName:',event.MessageName
        print 'Message:',event.Message
        print 'Time:',event.Time
        print 'Window:',event.Window
        print 'WindowName:',event.WindowName
        print 'Position:',event.Position
        print 'Wheel:',event.Wheel
        print 'Injected:',event.Injected
        print '---'
        #time.sleep(1) #If I uncomment this, running the program will freeze stuff, as mentioned earlier.
        return True

Record = record()
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = Record.OnMouseEvent
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

When I used pyHook the same way to detect keys up and down on keyboard it showed me only key down

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event): 
    print ('MessageName:',event.MessageName )
    print ('Message:',event.Message)
    print ('Time:',event.Time)
    print ('Window:',event.Window)
    print ('WindowName:',event.WindowName)
    print ('Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii) )
    print ('Key:', event.Key)
    print ('KeyID:', event.KeyID)
    print ('ScanCode:', event.ScanCode)
    print ('Extended:', event.Extended)
    print ('Injected:', event.Injected)
    print ('Alt', event.Alt)
    print ('Transition', event.Transition)
    print ('---')    
    return True
# When the user presses a key down anywhere on their system 
# the hook manager will call OnKeyboardEvent function.     
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
try:
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

How can I detect key up as well?

Answer (score 3):

This is really late, but hopefully it helps somebody. You are only registering the hook manager to key down events, so those are the only ones showing. You need to subscribe to KeyUp events as well. You can register them to the same function, shown, but note that probably for a project you'll want to subscribe them to different methods.

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event): 
    print ('MessageName:',event.MessageName )
    print ('Message:',event.Message)
    print ('Time:',event.Time)
    print ('Window:',event.Window)
    print ('WindowName:',event.WindowName)
    print ('Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii) )
    print ('Key:', event.Key)
    print ('KeyID:', event.KeyID)
    print ('ScanCode:', event.ScanCode)
    print ('Extended:', event.Extended)
    print ('Injected:', event.Injected)
    print ('Alt', event.Alt)
    print ('Transition', event.Transition)
    print ('---')    
    return True

# When the user presses a key down anywhere on their system 
# the hook manager will call OnKeyboardEvent function.     
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
# Here we register the same function to the KeyUp event. 
# Probably in practice you will create a different function to handle KeyUp functionality
hm.KeyUp = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
try:
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Also, depending on your version of Python you may encounter errors if you don't return True at the end of OnKeyboardEvent. You may also want to spend some time reading HookManager.py. Happy keylogging! Er uh, stay safe kids